# Apple Configurator 2 can't install or remove profiles after reinstall

Tags: macos, ios, apple-configurator

After deleting Apple Configurator 2 from my Mac and installing it again from the App Store, I am unable to install new configuration profiles or remove any existing profiles on my supervised iOS devices.

When trying to install new profiles, it shows the error message:

> An unexpected error has occurred with "Device Name". The profile must be installed using a device management tool. [DMCInstallationErrorDomain – 0xFB4 (4020)]

When trying to remove an existing profile, it shows:

> An unexpected error has occurred with "Device Name". The profile “Profile name” does not have the expected certificate for removal. [DMCInstallationErrorDomain – 0xFA8 (4008)]

Does anyone know how to solve this? I would like to avoid having to erase and reset the devices, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

Apple Configurator won’t touch devices it didn’t configure.

It’s not clear what “reinstalling Apple Configurator 2” means in your question.

Can you review this and see if you need to restore the data needed to supervise that device?

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/101974

> **Preserve or migrate data for Apple Configurator**
> Learn how to back up and restore data from Apple Configurator.
> You might need to reinstall macOS on your Apple Configurator workstation or migrate to a new workstation. Here’s how to make sure you can continue to supervise the same iOS devices.

I would make a backup of the data you have now and then contact Apple support to review your options. Erasing all the devices is a poor outcome (which will work for sure to start entirely over), but you might be stuck if you don’t have any other backups you could try restoring.

I would make sure Apple validates the version of the tool before you erase the Mac and attempt a restore. In the past, we had mixed results using Time Machine to get a working config and had to set reminders to export this data regularly and keep it secure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I uninstalled Apple Configurator from my mac and installed it again afterwards. The iOS devices were previously configured on the same machine, before I uninstalled Apple Configurator. I unfortunately didn't make a backup before uninstalling. The support article seems to refer to migrating to a new machine or reinstalling macOS. But I am using the same Mac and the same OS installation. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you contacted Apple Support? They would know if uninstalling the app trashes that data store by design or if you just were unlucky. In the past, we would always do this before even updating the app. I don’t know where the current design stores this data.

Comment: The reason to check with Apple is how they designed this is crucial and not documented. They know if an app removal is intended to cause this store to be unusable. They also are equipped to do the troubleshooting with you to understand what “reinstalling” was in precise detail. It often matters how you got the app and how you “uninstalled”.

Answer (score -2):

Delete all existing profiles from the device then try to reinstall it.

Comment: I am unable to delete the profiles on the devices themselves, as the profiles are set to disallow users from removing them. Trying to delete them in Apple Configurator yields the error message above, as I have mentioned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This won’t fix the pairing record on the Mac which either broke by design or broke by chance.. see my answer for more details on the issue at hand.